# Waiting for Tasks to finish in a list with ContinueWith

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task

**Update**
Added the missing code for adding in taskList

I have a list of task, that I await on..

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(myFilesDirectory);
var listOfTasks = new List<Tasks>();
files.ToList().ForEach(file => {
    var localFile = file // to avoid any closure issue
    listOfTasks.Add(ProcessMyFileTask(localFile));
});
await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("All done!");
```

Here's the ProcessMyFileTask

```
private async Task<List<string>> ProcessMyFileTask(string filePath)
    {
        using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(filePath))
        {
            string line;
            if ((line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                return DumpHexInLog(line);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The message shows up when all files are processed. But if I add a continuation task, like this..

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(myFilesDirectory);
var listOfTasks = new List<Tasks>();
files.ToList().ForEach(file => {
    var localFile = file // to avoid any closure issue
    listOfTasks.Add(ProcessMyFileTask(localFile).ContinueWith(list => 
            ValidateHexDumpsTask(list.Result, localFile)));
});
await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("All done!");
```

Then what Tasks will be awaited on? I mean would `"All Done!"` come after all the `ProcessMyFileTask` is done? Or will it come after all the `ValidateHexDumpsTask` are done too?

When I tested it, it came after the `ValidateHexDumpsTask` but I am not sure if that will certainly be always the case, as this might have been because of some threading condition or such.

Comment: First point: you don't need that `localFile = file`. In this case `file` is a parameter to the lambda expression. It's not capturing anything else.

Comment: Next, it's not clear where you're ever populating `listOfTasks`. It's really hard to help when we can only see pseudo-code. Please provide a [mcve] instead. (They don't have to be real files, of course - just strings would be fine...)

Comment: This is still pseudo-code - it wouldn't compile due to `forEach` not being `ForEach`. Again, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It's still not complete though. If it were, I could copy and paste the code into a completely new file, compile it and run it.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ? any final solutions ?

Comment: What is `DumpHexInLog`  and `ValidateHexDumpsTask` ? *completely new file, compile it and run it.*

Answer (score 2):

It will complete only when both the `ProcessMyFiles` methods and `ValidateHexDumps` are done.

However, `ContinueWith` is not recommended. It's a low-level, dangerous API. You should use `await` instead:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(myFilesDirectory);
var listOfTasks = files.Select(ProcessAndValidateAsync);
await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks);
Console.WriteLine("All done!");


async Task ProcessAndValidateAsync(string file)
{
  var list = await ProcessMyFileTask(localFile);
  ValidateHexDumps(list, localFile);
}
```

Comment: No; `ContinueWith` returns a new task that represents the continuation.

Comment: [`ContinueWith` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) for the same reasons that [`StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html): in short, 1) It doesn't understand `async`; 2) It uses a default scheduler other than `TaskScheduler.Default`; 3) it doesn't have appropriate option defaults for asynchronous tasks (`DenyChildAttach`).

Answer (score 0):

`WhenAll` will be completed when `ValidateHexDumps` has finished running on each of the items.

`ContinueWith` returns a `Task` that represents the completion of the continuation, not the completion of the task that it is a continuation of.